# foreach Controls in C# in descending order

Tags: c#, foreach, controls

I have this piece of FOREACH code which makes part of music notes

```
foreach (MusicNote mn in pictureBox1.Controls)
{
    sp.SoundLocation = @"..\\..\\bin\\Debug\\sound\\mapped\\" + mn.pitch+ ".wav"; //find that pressed note
    Thread.Sleep(mn.duration * 100); //The Ticks * 100 to convert them into milliseconds
    sp.Play(); //play it
}
```

This should traverse all the Controls and play them one by one but the problem is that it starts from the last one added instead of the first one like I wish it to be meaning it's playing in **descending** order NOT **ascending** like I wish it to be. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Why not use a classic `for` loop?

Comment: as then I need more controls over it as well, like show the music notes and so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pictureBox1.Controls.Cast<Control>().Reverse()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. thank you very much :) What does the CAST do exactly please it seems like a sort of List

Comment: Also is there a way how to CLEAR all the Controls AFTER I do the Control Traversal please?

Comment: @DodoSerebro `is there a way how to CLEAR all the Controls AFTER I do the Control Traversal please?` -1 one question at a time.

Comment: 1. Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type (`Control` in your case).

Comment: 2. Must be `pictureBox1.Controls.Clear();`

Comment: This is a poor answer -  it's just a line of code with no explanation. Contrast this answer with [this one from adrianbanks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20734874/109702) - the difference is obvious. You'll probably find that you got lucky and this answer worked this time - it won't work all the time, and can be largely useless to other readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the controls in the `Controls` property is based on the z-index of each control (as the `Controls` property returns a [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not just a normal list).

You can control the z-index of each control by using the [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. If you explicitly control the z-index using this method when adding the controls (you don't say how the controls are added so I'm assuming that you do it manually in code), they should come out in the order you want when you iterate over the `Controls` property.

Comment: Care explaining a bit the SetChildIndex more please?? What does it do exactly? I have a keyboard and when I press the Keys it does a music Note consiting of pitch,duration and the shape ..

Comment: @DodoSerebro: The position of each control can be set explicitly. This enables you to put them at a specific position in what is in effect an ordered list. `SetChildIndex` allows you to put a control in a particular position (e.g. if you have eight controls, you can put the control you want to come first at position zero).

Comment: that makes sense, so if I Set the first element as position 0, automatically all the others behind that element line up automatically as 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @DodoSerebro: I wouldn't assume that. I would explicitly set them all at the position you want, especially as it sounds like you know how many you have and in what order they should be.